# Ajuda para um exercicio em JavaScript com for...of e join()

Tags: javascript

Dado o seguinte vetor de objetos:

```
var usuarios = [
  {
    nome: 'Diego',
    habilidades: ['Javascript', 'ReactJS', 'Redux']
  },
  {
    nome: 'Gabriel',
    habilidades: ['VueJS', 'Ruby on Rails', 'Elixir']
  }
];
```

Escreva uma função que produza o seguinte resultado:

```
O Diego possui as habilidades: Javascript, ReactJS, Redux
O Gabriel possui as habilidades: VueJS, Ruby on Rails, Elixir
```

Dica: Para percorrer um vetor você deve utilizar a sintaxe `for...of` e para unir valores de um array com um separador utilize o `join`.

Comment: qual a sua duvida em especifico? o que você já fez do seu exercício?

Comment: não estou conseguindo usar o método for...of e join

Comment: Eduardo não me leve à mal por favor, mas não seria certo eu postar aqui uma solução pois você não iria aprender. Até porque isso parece um exercicio e assim sendo, o intuito é de você praticar. Da uma olhada nesse site: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
tem muito conteudo que vai te ajudar.

se voce tiver começado a fazer o exercicio, posta o que você já tem e os problemas que está ocorrendo

Comment: eu só não estou conseguindo juntar as strings com join()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa primeiro percorrer cada objeto do array `usuarios` e depois imprimir no console os seus atributos. Para imprimir as habilidades de cada usuário em uma só linha, utilize o método `join` para juntar todos os elementos numa só String. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
var usuarios = [
    {
      nome: 'Diego',
      habilidades: ['Javascript', 'ReactJS', 'Redux']
    },
    {
      nome: 'Gabriel',
      habilidades: ['VueJS', 'Ruby on Rails', 'Elixir']
    }
]

for (let usuario of usuarios){
    console.log('O ' + usuario.nome + ' possui as habilidades: ' + usuario.habilidades.join(", "));
}
```

Para ficar no formato do que está se pedindo no exercício, eu passei como parâmetro do `join` o separador `", "`, para que tenha um espaçamento entre a vírgula e o valor.

Comment: E o `for...of` ?